# BOM with Sets/Phantom along with automatic purchase order creation

Tags: odoo

Below is a quite complex scenario in openerp which i am trying to implement.

In openerp there's an option to deliver bill of materials when the sales order has a finished product. This is possible by specifying the BOM type as Sets/ Phantom. This required the product type to be manufacture and not buy.

There's also an option to generate automatically the purchase order on conforming the sales order. This requires the product type to be buy and not manufacture.

I would require both the functionality whereas openerp allows only one. Is there a way to do both. Kindly clarify. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way now. Buying or manufacturing from sale order is mainly done by the procurement and in procurement it checks the supply method of the product. If you want to achieve this, you have to add the supply method in the sale order line and specify the supply method from the sale order line like we are specifying the procurement method from sale order line. Then change the way how suppy method is selecting in the procurement.